# creation of java0.log file and .lck file can be disabled using logmanger.reset() ,but i want to do this based on some config parameter

Tags: java, java.util.logging

Java creating logfile `java0.log` and lock file in `/root` folder

This behavior can be disabled using `LogManager.reset()` function, but I want to call this function based on some configuration parameter.

Can anyone suggest which config file I can use to do this and how to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [java.util.logging.config.file](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/logging/LogManager.html) system property and point it to the [NUL device](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_device).

On Windows:

```
-Djava.util.logging.config.file=NUL
```

On Linux:

```
-Djava.util.logging.config.file=/dev/null
```

On any platform you can simply create an empty file and point to it.

What this does is on startup the [LogManager.readConfiguration()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/logging/LogManager.html#readConfiguration--) is called with the given file path (stream).  Per the contract this method will:

> Reinitialize the logging properties and reread the logging configuration

When it reads the logging configuration there is no new data to read.  Therefore, this behaves as if it was just calling [LogManager.reset()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/logging/LogManager.html#reset--) on startup.

If you want more selective behavior on the root logger then you write a custom class and use the `java.util.logging.config.class` property:

```
package foo.bar;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.util.logging.FileHandler;
import java.util.logging.Handler;
import java.util.logging.LogManager;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public final class LogConfig {

    public LogConfig() throws Throwable {
        //Load the default config file.
        String file = System.getProperty("java.util.logging.config.file");
        if (file != null) {
            LogManager.getLogManager().readConfiguration(new FileInputStream(file));
        }

        //Modify the logger tree if property is set.
        String key = "some.config.property";
        String v = System.getProperty(key);
        if (v == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException("System property '"
                    + key + "' was not defined");
        }

        if (Boolean.parseBoolean(v)) {
            Logger root = Logger.getLogger("");
            for (Handler h : root.getHandlers()) {
                if (h instanceof FileHandler) {
                    root.removeHandler(h);
                    h.close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The to use this class you set the following command line properties:

```
-Djava.util.logging.config.file=/path/to/file -Djava.util.logging.config.class=foo.bar.LogConfig -Dsome.config.property=true
```

Comment: Reinitialize logging properties means I have to add all other parameters in existing logging.properties file in this new file along with my ne parameter to reset LogManagerright ?

Comment: when we use this config.file system property does this means that all other config params in existing logging.properties file get ignored ?

Comment: @yuvrajK Right.  The system property controls the file input into LogManager.readConfiguration.  They may be ignored or not.  Order of operations will change the logging config you end up with.  The system property runs at JVM boot.